# SonarQube task causes vs test platform instailler task Azure Pipeline to fail

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest

We are running multiple Azure pipelines on an on-prem environment, which very similar.
Today I added SonarQube tasks on one of them for integration with SonarQube.

1. Prepare for Analysis
2. Run Code Analysis
3. publish Quality gateway result

Now the Task for '**Visual Studio test platform installer**' fails and reports

> ##[error]This task is supported only on Windows agents and cannot be used on other platforms.

And as soon as I remove the SonarQube tasks the pipeline works again. The pipeline never passes the first SQ task and reordering does not help.

Update:

I removed tasks 2 and 3 and the pipeline works.
As soon as a I add step 2, it fails again

Update: CI yaml content added

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  batch: True
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/develop
jobs:
- job: Phase_1
  displayName: Phase 1
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Use Node 14.x
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 14.x
      checkLatest: true
  - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
    displayName: Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.101
    inputs:
      version: 6.0.101
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
    displayName: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
    inputs:
      SonarQube: XXX
      projectKey: XXX
      projectName: XXX
  - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
    displayName: VsTest Platform Installer
    inputs:
      versionSelector: specificVersion
      testPlatformVersion: 16.8.3
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    displayName: Use NuGet 5.8.x
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 5.8.x
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet custom
    inputs:
      command: custom
      projects: '**/XXX.sln'
      custom: restore
      arguments: --source https://XXX -r win-x86
      selectOrConfig: config
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet build
    inputs:
      projects: '**/XXX.sln'
      arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="bin\WebAppContent" /p:BuildPlatform="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:BuildConfiguration="$(BuildConfiguration)"
  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: Build solution **/XXX.sln
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      solution: '**/XXX.sln'
      msbuildLocationMethod: location
      msbuildLocation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
      platform: $(BuildPlatform)
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
      msbuildArguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="bin\WebAppContent" /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x86
      maximumCpuCount: true
      logProjectEvents: true
  - task: VSTest@2
    name: VSTest_4
    displayName: Test Assemblies **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: >-
        **\*unittest*.dll

        !**\obj\**

        !**\ref\**
      runOnlyImpactedTests: false
      vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
      runInParallel: true
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      platform: $(BuildPlatform)
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
    displayName: Run Code Analysis
  - task: SonarQubePublish@5
    displayName: Publish Quality Gate Result
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive Apps.Api
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: source\Apps\Apps.Api\bin\WebAppContent
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).Apps.Api.zip
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive Hub.Api
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: source\Hub\Hub.Api\bin\WebAppContent
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).Hub.Api.zip
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive Rmi.Api
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: source\Rmi\Rmi.Api\bin\WebAppContent
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).Rmi.Api.zip
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive Hub.WebClient
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: source\Hub\Hub.WebClient\bin\WebAppContent
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).Hub.WebClient.zip
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    name: CopyFiles_5
    displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
      Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\PublishOutput\**'
      TargetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      CleanTargetFolder: true
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    name: PublishBuildArtifacts_6
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
...
```

Comment: Im actually having a similar issue right now. The sonarqube task Run Code Analysis causes my build to hang with the message "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests." When I disable it, the pipeline works properly.

Answer (score 0):

> SonarQube task causes vs test platform instailler task Azure Pipeline to fail

According to the document [Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops):

> **Use this task to acquire the Microsoft test platform** from nuget.org or
> a specified feed, and add it to the tools cache. The installer task
> satisfies the 'vstest' demand and a subsequent Visual Studio Test task
> in a build or release pipeline can run without needing a full Visual
> Studio install on the agent machine.

So, the task Visual Studio test platform installer is supported only on Windows agents and cannot be used on other platforms.

You could just add this task and run it on other platforms, you will get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
Azure devops is running on Windows and in our case an on-prem Windows server.
The pipeline runs perfectly without the SonarQube tasks

Comment: @JimmyAD, Thanks for your reply. Would you please share your YAML file or pipeline configuration to us, so that we could check it.

Comment: yaml content added in question.